# No mime type given

Tags: php, mime-types

I am currently building a PHP application that lets users upload files. I am currently at the upload page, but my verification system does not work. I am using this system to validate files as audio files.

```
// Set our file name and extension
$fname     = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$extension = strtolower(substr($fname, strpos($fname, '.') + 1));

// Check file
if ($extension == 'mp3' && $_FILES['file']['type'] == 'audio/mpeg') {
    //File is valid mp3
} else {
    //File is invalid
}
```

Now this doesn't work, but the weird thing is when I echo out `$_FILES['file']['type']` it does not echo out a mime type for audio files. When I do this for any other file type, it echoes it out successfully.

It doesn't give a mime type only for audio files. I have tried it with WAV and M4A files, and it doesn't return one with any of these either. Is it something with the file type, or do I have to edit the .htaccess file or the MIME.types file in my xampp server. Also could there be a better way to validate uploaded files?

Also note that it does this on my xampp server, and the free server that I am using for test purposes.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$_FILES['file']['type']` comes from the browser that uploads the file so you can't rely on this value at all.

Check out [`finfo_file`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.finfo-file.php) for identifying file types based on file content.  The extension of the file is also unreliable as the user could upload malicious code with an mp3 extension.

Comment: How would I go about installing this extension on a windows XAMPP environment/linux server?

Comment: See http://www.php.net/manual/en/fileinfo.installation.php  Basically its already installed on Linux PHP 5.3+